# Javascript error logging/reporting/tracker for packaged mobile apps (Android, iOS)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, error-logging, error-reporting

Is there any open source project for error tracking/logging, both mobile library and server app?

I mean, catch non-handled exceptions in JS on a packaged app via Phonegap (Android, iOS) and send them to a server that can be deployed locally (Not as Crashlytics)?

Thanks

Comment: There are paid services you can use for this, so you don't have to host your own infrastructure. I cofounded http://trackjs.com, which has been installed on a lot of mobile apps.

Comment: Yes I know. However I can't host the information externally so I need to deploy the server by myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try open source error monitoring tool https://github.com/getsentry with javascript library https://github.com/getsentry/raven-js. I don't know how easy it is to deploy in your own server.

If you are looking for paid services, you can try

- https://www.atatus.com/
- https://trackjs.com/
- https://bugsnag.com